# QGIS Error when using geometry generation to draw a line to a polygon

Tags: qgis

I need to create a map of a property and the setbacks of various structures within the property to its boundary. I have a shapefile of all properties and use a selection filter to isolate the one I am after, and this is one layer. The geometry type for that is "Polygon". Another layer is buildings, with geometry type of "Polygon".

Within the building layer, I have symbology of type geometry generator, with the following code:

```
shortest_line( centroid($geometry),aggregate('Lot 1','collect',$geometry))
```

There are no errors shown but it also does not generate a line.

I changed the above code to point it at another layer of type "Line", with a line feature, and it generates the shortest line as expected.

Does geometry generation work against a line-segment that is part of a closed Polygon? If not, what do I need to do? If it should, any idea what is going on? This is QGIS 3.14.

Once I get the line-drawing to work, I will add a label of the distance.

Comment: What is the expression supposed to do? Draw a line from each building centroid to?

Comment: It will draw the shortest line from the centroid of an object (a building in this case) to a line. The length of that line is the nearest that the center of the building will be to the property boundary, which is what I am after.

Comment: Your expression should work. Please post a screenshot and share sample data. Otherwise, we could just start guessing. Depends on a lot of things: single part/muiltipart lines? CRS used? etc.

Comment: If you apply the expression on a polygon layer (buildings) and the layer `Lot 1` is a line layer, try this: `shortest_line(centroid($geometry),overlay_nearest('Lot 1',$geometry)[0])`. Does this work?

Comment: Lot 1 is a Polygon layer. For some reason, overlap_nearest is not available for geometry generation in v 3.14. The expression editor says "unknown function", even though it is in the docs for 3.14

Comment: @ScottW Is it because you misspelled it? It's `overlay_nearest()`, not `overlap_nearest()`. Also, make sure that your Lot 1 polygon and your centroids are in the same CRS and they are ideally in a projected CRS (units in feet/metres).

Comment: The Lot 1 CRS is the same as the centroid CRS. "overlap_nearest" in my comment was a typo by me; I meant overlay_nearest. I found a work-around - I ran the tool "Polygon to Lines" on the Lot 1 polygon, which produced a virtual layer, and then used that layer rather than "Lot 1" in the expression for the geometry generator. That worked.

Comment: @Babel - See my other comment, that running "Polygon to Line" tool, and then using the output of that, solved the problem. Note that this is a problem of finding distances of structures in a property to the closest property line, so the points are inside a polygon. All I can think is that "shortest_line" does not work for a point inside of a polygon.